# how to send custom parameters via manychat sdk in widget growth tools

Tags: javascript, sdk

Manychat (lead platform and marketing funnel) has an SDK library that allows you to send custom parameters.

I need to send an SRC name parameter (with value set by me) to identify where my client came from. Using Growth Tools.

Via direct link is easy and works just insert the value at the end of the link followed by - this way:

https://m.me/243522816336294?ref=w4490007--value

Already with the other widgets it is possible to do via ManyChat SDK

Reading the documentation should work as follows but it does not work:

MC.getWidget(243522833566294).setPayload("value")

someone help me?

Comment: Hi can you share an example of what you have tried so far? Is there an error message that you receive?

Comment: according to the documentation. I tried to send the parameter through the function of the SDK .. ( MC.getWidget(243522833566294).setPayload("value")  )but it does not work.